# What is wrong with my DateFormatting?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Here is my code

```
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yy/MM/dd (EEE)"
```

Here is my data (selectedNotifications)

```
2015-12-16 10:26:31 +0000
```

When I format like this,

```
cell.receivedDate.text = "From XXX on " + fmt.stringFromDate(selectedNotificaitons.createdAt)
```

It showed me like this

```
From XXX on 58/12/16 (Wed)
```

What is wrong with me?why the year is 58 instead of 15

Comment: How did you check the value of `selectedNotificaitons.createdAt`? Perhaps it's actually an earlier date parsing failure? What happens if you use a format with `yyyy` instead of `yy`? (As an aside, that's an odd format - normally a year-first format is the ISO yyyy-MM-dd format.)

Comment: when i use "yyyy/MM/dd (EE)" -> 2558/12/16 (Wed)

Comment: Clearly, the value of  `selectedNotificaitons.createdAt` is not what you think. Get its time interval directly and check its value.

Comment: What do you get if you set the locale with `fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` ?

Comment: Thanks @Raphaël,u help me out.I answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the locale to `en_US_POSIX` to tell Swift to use the gregorian calendar.

```
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have posted above is correct. I tried on the playground and it resulted in correct output

So the error lies in your `selectedNotificaitons.createdAt`. Print the createdAt property and check it

[image]

Comment: Before formatting it came to me like that ->2015-12-16 10:26:31 +0000. After formatting -> 2558/12/16 (Wed).I don't know whats wrong.createdDate was NSDate which used to store at Realm database.

Comment: @6245Htarwara its string, you need to convert it to date first then convert it to string in desired format.